# Getting exception after deploying jersey code on TomCat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jersey-client

I am learning jersey to upload files on server.Got below code from net which is working fine if i am running it through NetBeans but if i deploy the .war file through TomCat then i am getting exception.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>File Upload with Jersey</h1>

<form action="rest/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" />
   </p>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

UploadFileService .class

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/"
            + fileDetail.getFileName().substring(2);


            System.out.println(uploadedFileLocation+"================="+fileDetail.getFileName());
    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            FileUpload.html
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I refered  [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/570630/Web-Services/java/Run-Simple-Jersey-REST-Webservice) link and added all the required jar files:

- jersey-core-1.18
- jersey-multipart-1.18
- jersey-server-1.18
- jersey-servlet-1.18
- asm-3.1

still i am getting below exception

```
exception 

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:825)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)

Jul 14, 2014 8:00:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /rest threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method     com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:825)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that only Glassfish supports Jersey not even JBoss & TomCat

Answer (score 1):

I am using Tomcat and Jetty for Jersey. So it is supported.

The solution for your problem would be to add jersey-bundle from here (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle). Choose any one from late releases. I used 1.8 to solve the issue.